# Draw five transparent circles on the google map v2 by taking current location as the center of circle

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I need to draw five circle-circle on the Google Maps v2 by taking the current location as the center of a circle. Meaning that each of the five circles have the same center but with different radii: the first circle will have radius of 10m, second circle radius of 20m, third circle radius of 30m, fourth circle radius of 40m, and fifth circle radius of 50m. I am using Google Maps v2.

And I need to show a marker on the center of the circle as well.

I am trying something like this to draw the circle on the Google Map v2 but it draws only one circle and not the five circum-circle

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                  .center(latLng)   //set center
                  .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
                  .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
                  .strokeColor(0x10000000)
                  .strokeWidth(5);

                  myCircle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

I need to draw circum-circle exactly like this-

[image]

Can anybody help me with this? I am having problem in making this circle in Google Map v2. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tech, I've removed the code blocks from the first paragraph of your post. I see you've used them a lot in earlier posts. I suggest that you refrain - code block formatting is intended for elements of code, not for text highlighting, and is pretty hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will make sure that next time.

Comment: That question doesn't answers my question. You can read the answer as well in that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(int rad=100;rad<=500;rad+100)
{

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
              .center(latLng)   //set center
              .radius(rad)   //set radius in meters
              .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
              .strokeColor(0x10000000)
              .strokeWidth(5);

              myCircle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
}
```